# Are chess learning tools on topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I am an old SO/SE contributor, but new on chess.SE, so please pardon my question.

I just posted:

[More visual display of possible moves in opening explorers / databases](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/33794/more-visual-display-of-possible-moves-in-opening-explorers-databases)

but it was closed as "opinion-based".

This is quite strange because, by definition, discussions and advice about chess positions/games (>50% of the content on this site?) is highly subject to subjective interpretation ("this is a good move", etc.)

I am maybe sad because I spent 30 minute writing the question and doing a mockup graphic, and I really thought it could be interesting for many learning situations, but more generally:

**Are questions about chess learning tools on topic for this site?**

Answer (score 2):

> how would it be possible (either with this website or another) to see it like this

and

> It would be great to visualize in the blink of an eye the top-4 options for a given position in an opening

both invite discussion about hypothetical feature requests for other platforms.

This is not a discussion site.

It is also not a support site for other sites. Make your feature requests and suggestions directly to those sites not this one. Your question could equally have been closed for being off topic.

Feature requests for this (Chess) site, if that is what you want to do, belong on Chess Meta not the the main Chess forum.

Comment: Thank you for your input. There *could* be a helpful answer like *"Yes, this well-known open-source software XYZ does this visualization, and it is useful for opening learners"*, so there are potential answers on-topic. It's not only about websites.